# Should injection tag be added to all questions about various injections?

Tags: discussion, tags

There is [injection](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/injection). But except this tag there are also [xss](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xss), [sql-injection](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-injection), [path-injection](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/path-injection) etc.

Should all questions with those tags be also tagged with [injection](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/injection)? If not, when [injection](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/injection) should be used?

For example, is usage of [injection](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/injection) appropriate in [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17642/validate-ip-addresses)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using [injection](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/injection) only for injection attacks where there is not a more specific injection tag available.

- For XSS attacks, use [xss](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xss), not [injection](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/injection).
- For SQL injection attacks, use [sql-injection](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-injection), not [injection](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/injection).
- For path injection attacks, use [path-injection](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/path-injection), not [injection](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/injection).
- For other injection-style attacks that do not have a more specific tag, you could use [injection](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/injection).  For example, you might use [injection](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/injection) on a question about a command injection attack.

For instance, you asked about what the tags should be on [Should IP addresses be validated to prevent SQL Injection?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/17642/971).  By my guidelines above, the right set of tags is [sql-injection](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-injection) but not [injection](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/injection).

Comment: Definitely agree here - because XSS, SQLi and Path injection are well known, definite types of attack it aids clarity to specify the tag. For others the generic injection tag is useful. If a new class of injection attacks becomes common, it may then make sense to create a new specific one.

Comment: Tag descriptions should describe appropriate usage.

Answer (score 0):

First, I added the [injection](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/injection) tag to [Should IP addresses be validated to prevent SQL Injection?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17642/should-ip-addresses-be-validated-to-prevent-sql-injection).

Well tagging question, except when the scope of the tag is really obvious, I usually consult the help text of the tag:

[About **injection**](https://security.stackexchange.com/tags/injection/info)

> inserting malicious content, usually code (like SQL, Javascript) 
>   into a vulnerable application

In this case the help text explicitly makes the tag appropriate for both SQL injection and XSS.

(When the help text is too vague, unclear, or even missing, I see which other questions use the tag and try to stay consistent with existing usage.)